# If I redistribute my Visual Studio solution, will $(SolutionDir) have the new value of the folder at the receiver end?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I would like to send the Solution directory to someone, I use $(SolutionDir) as a path in including headers (headers are in the solution directory).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the `$(SolutionDir)` variable is expanded when Visual Studio loads the project/solution so it will always be correct and based on the user's environment.